# Why sqlplus spoolfile cutting last column?

Tags: sql, oracle, export-to-csv, sqlplus, spool

i have problems with spooling file to .csv. Sqlplus cutting off last column name and I don't know why? I am trying to set bigger linesize but it doesn't work.

Thanks for any tips

```
set embedded on 
set pagesize 0
set linesize 600
set colsep ';'
set echo off
set feedback off
--set trimspool off
set headsep off
SET HEADING OFF   
SET TRUNCATE OFF
SET WRAP OFF

column_1 AS COLUMN1, column_2 AS COLUMN2, column_3 AS COLUMN3, 'FAKEMESSAGE' as COLUMN4
```

And COLUMN4 is cut, I see just string "COL"

Comment: Actually, your code doesn't even run.  You have no SELECT,  and the use of AS is invalid.

Comment: of course, i didnt paste the whole code .... the important part is written

Comment: Can you give us the column size from the schema for COLUMN1, COLUMN2 and COLUMN3 ? And your Oracle database version / sqlplus client version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I already solved the problem - when you want to use to your select some unexisted column, in my case -  'FAKEMESSAGE' as COLUMN4 - in real select i had just 'FAKE' as COLUMN4 - and COLUMN4 was just COLU - i know why - because when the column doesnt really exist in the table/database, the table dont really know how big the column should be, so it copy the size of inputed value and the same size of string put on the name of column, so if you want to have header size of 8 strings char, you have to setup first OR the input value have to be at the same size ...

Comment: You should be able to accept this as an answer